# Protect direct access to public folder (folder name: "services") but allow www.example-site.com/services/list_of_users URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I have a folder called services in my public directory and it has images, If I call URL "www.example-site.com/services" it shows directory with the list of images.

I have a URL called "www.example-site.com/services/list_of_users" and it displays user information with images.

If I Restrict access to files in public folder "services" this URL will not work "www.example-site.com/services/list_of_users"

My .htaccess file:

order allow,deny

   al

Please help me!

Comment: order allow,deny
<Files ~ "\.(mp4|flv|mkv|3gp|avi|ogg|m4p|mpeg|wmv|webm|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$">
   allow from all
</Files>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just adding an empty `index.html` file in your services directory?

Comment: For quick Fix, It Works!!! but need a permanent fix which actually works

Comment: @Nithin I would recommend using htaccess if you're using apache server.

Comment: .htaccess throwing forbidden 403 error for www.example-site.com/services/list_of_users and protecting my media files